# Adding additional users to view ALL my Google Analytics assets

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-cloud-console

I am a Google Analytics consultant and have around 30 properties I have access to on my Google Analytics. Each of the properties owners gave me Read & Analyze rights.
Now I'd like my coworker to view these properties and don't want to give him my email and password (obviously). How can I give him access with his own email?

I would also like him to be able to access the properties through the [Google Analytics Query explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/). Maybe there is a way I can add him to the Cloud Console?

Answer (score 1):

You can't give someone else access to a Google Analytics account for which you only have Read and Analyze rights:

> > Manage Users: Can manage account users (add/delete users, assign permissions). Does not include Edit or Collaborate.
> >
> > Edit: Can perform administrative and report-related functions (e.g., add/edit/delete accounts, properties, views, filters, goals, etc., but not manage users), and see report data. Includes Collaborate.
> >
> > Collaborate: Can create personal assets, and share them. Can collaborate on shared assets, for example, edit a dashboard or annotation. Includes Read & Analyze.
> >
> > Read & Analyze: Can see report and configuration data; can manipulate data within reports (e.g., filter a table, add a secondary dimension, create a segment); can create personal assets, and share them, and see shared assets. Cannot collaborate on shared assets.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2884495?hl=en&ref_topic=1009690

Only Manager Users access can do that.

You can share assets with other who have been granted access to the analytics account but not with someone who has not been granted any access.

You can't grant a co-worker access to the Query Explorer to an account that they don't have access to and you can't grant access through the Cloud Console either. You couldn't do that even with the highest level.

Access can only be granted from within Google Analytics by someone with Manage User rights.